# Update or insert meta key value - On Duplicate key update

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I need to bulk update some meta descriptions and have found that some of the posts don't have them so I need to do an update or insert query.

(Once I get this query right I will be creating a temp table and insert using a CSV)

I have so far got to the following:

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id,meta_key,meta_value )
VALUES ('1117','_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', 'Test 5')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE post_id = 1117, meta_key='_yoast_wpseo_metadesc'
```

But this just inserts a new row.

So if a row exists with the post_id and the meta_key='_yoast_wpseo_metadesc' I need to update this row.

If a row doesn't have  meta_key='_yoast_wpseo_metadesc' I need to insert a new row witht the post_id, meta_key and meta_value.

Any help appreciated

Comment: `Select * from wp_postmeta Where POST_ID='1117' and meta_key='_yoast_wpseo_metadesc'` Change the post ids in the above query and store all post ids where num_rows is 0 and run insert on those and update on others.

Answer (score -1):

Use WP's [`update_post_meta()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/) instead of straight SQL. If the postmeta exists, it gets updated. If it doesn't exist, it gets added.

```
update_post_meta('1117', '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', 'Test 5');
```